# After Minify Enabled true in gradle apk not working properly

Tags: android

When i set `minifyenabled false`,apk runs properly but when i set `minify enabled true` in release mode in gradle file various error and warning is showing and signed apk is not properly.

This is the Problem

> Warning:library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends or implements program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner
>   Warning:library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
>   Warning:library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
>   Warning:library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestSuite
>   Warning:library class android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase
>   Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
>   Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
>   Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
>   Warning:org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean
>   Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
>   Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
>   Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
>   Warning:org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean
>   Warning:there were 10 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
>            If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
>            the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
>   Warning:there were 5 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
>            You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
>            be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
>   Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 5.962 secs
>   Information:1 error

My gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"



defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.newsreader.sitl"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                            onesignal_app_id               : "47642d28-5e08-40c7-ae54-9db8f39f2cbd",
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "660750131316"] }
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}
}
dependencies
{
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':pulltorefreshlibrary')
compile project(':aphidFlipViewLibrary')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile project(':volleynew')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.0'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Progaurd-rules.pro is:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application 
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service 
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver 
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider 
-dontwarn
```

Comment: "Progaurd-rules.pro is:" ???

Comment: After setting minify enabled to true my http url connection not working also
downloaded the apk from store but everything is working properly in my local machine